# Custom right click menu only show on children of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/TnbYm/

I'm trying to get my right click menu to only show on children of `#canvas`. I also want to have it remove when a child is not clicked, but one of the problems are because document is being called as the container document closes it before the action is called.

If anyone can help me with this it'll be greatly appreciated.

```
if ( $("#tm").prop('checked') === true ) {
    // Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
    $("#canvas").find("*").bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
        // Avoid the real one
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
        // Show contextmenu
        if ($("#showcustom-menu").show() === true) {
            $("#custom-menu").hide(100).
            // In the right position (the mouse)
            css({
                top: event.pageY + "px",
                left: event.pageX + "px"
            });
        } else {
            $("#custom-menu").show(100).
            // In the right position (the mouse)
            css({
                top: event.pageY + "px",
                left: event.pageX + "px"
            });
        }
    });

    // If the document is clicked somewhere
    $(document).bind("mousedown", function () {
        $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
    });
} else {
    $(document).unbind("contextmenu");
}
$("#tm").on('change', function() {
    if ( $(this).prop('checked') === true ) {
        // Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
        $("#canvas").find("*").bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
            // Avoid the real one
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
            // Show contextmenu
            if ($("#custom-menu").show() === true) {
                $("#custom-menu").hide(100).
                // In the right position (the mouse)
                css({
                    top: event.pageY + "px",
                    left: event.pageX + "px"
                });
            } else {
                $("#custom-menu").show(100).
                // In the right position (the mouse)
                css({
                    top: event.pageY + "px",
                    left: event.pageX + "px"
                });
            }
        });

        // If the document is clicked somewhere
        $(document).bind("mousedown", function () {
            $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
        });
    } else {
        $(document).unbind("contextmenu");
    }
});

// Menu's button actions
$("#custom-menu > button").click(function() {
    alert($(this).text() + "was clicked");
});
$("#custom-menu > button#duplicate").click(function() {
    // $('#canvas').append($(this).clone());
    $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
});
$("#custom-menu > button#remove").click(function() {
    // $(this).remove();
    $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
});
$("#custom-menu").find("button#deselect, button#close").click(function() {
    $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors for that:

```
$(document).on('contextmenu', function (e) {
    if (e.target.matches('#canvas *')) 
        alert('Contexted!');
    else 
        alert('Not contexted!');
});
```

[Element.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches)
*[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnbYm/4/)*

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have updated the jsfiddle provided by you please go through that..
its working fine and you can add code into the click method according to your need.

```
Link for jsfiddle:-  http://jsfiddle.net/TnbYm/14/
```